# Compare two Oracle database roles

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, permissions, role

I'm trying to re-engineer my corporates user managament and want to compare all the roles with each other to find duplicate ones. Doing it by hand is really tiring and I need to compare like 150 roles. I wrote the following script:

```
DEFINE ROLE_1 = &INPUT_1
DEFINE ROLE_2 = &INPUT_2

SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET LINESIZE 140

COLUMN PRIVILEGE    FORMAT A20    HEADING "PRIVILEGE"
COLUMN TABLE_NAME   FORMAT A30    HEADING "TABLE_NAME"
COLUMN GRANTABLE    FORMAT A5     HEADING "GRANTABLE"

PROMPT
PROMPT OVERLAPPINGS BETWEEN 1st ROLE AND 2nd ROLE
PROMPT

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_1' )

INTERSECT

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_2' )
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE ASC
/

PROMPT
PROMPT PRIVILEGES IN 1st ROLE BUT NOT IN 2nd ROLE
PROMPT

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_1' )

MINUS

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_2' )
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE ASC
/

PROMPT
PROMPT PRIVILEGES IN 2nd ROLE BUT NOT IN 1st ROLE
PROMPT

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_2' )

MINUS

SELECT
    PRIVILEGE,
    TABLE_NAME,
    GRANTABLE
FROM
    SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
    GRANTEE IN ( '&ROLE_1' )
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE ASC
/
```

It works all fine, but for some reason it doesn't display the table head.

The real problem why I'm asking is, is there a more comfortable way to automatically compare all roles to one another? Some neat way to do all this? I'm quite new to PL/SQL and don't really know how to loop this thing up. Is there even maybe a possibly way to display the corresponding column of the tables?

Comment: It's not an answer, but consider Oracle's hierarchical (`CONNECT BY`) queries using DBA_ROLE_PRIVS to navigate the role tree as well as using the INTERSET/MINUS operators to determine if one role includes all privileges of another role.

Comment: I already have a hierarchical query to list all roles of an user, so it wouldn't be a problem to change it into comparing two roles. The main problem is that I want the querie to do this for all the users automatically. Like fetching the content of `DBA_ROLES` and comparing it like some kind of A x A cartesian product.

Comment: One thing to consider is that `dba_role_privs` contains both users granted roles and roles granted roles. If you want duplicate roles, regardless of users, you will need the queries over `role_role_privs`, `role_sys_privs`, and `role_tab_privs`. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: So far it's correct, but I'm mostlikely using `dba_tab_privs' for comparing as you can see in my MWE. It would be nice, if there was a way to loop the whole query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query that finds duplicate role_tab_privs. It uses Oracle LISTAGG aggregate function to create a list of privileges for each role, owner, table.

```
SELECT arole, brole, aowner, atable, aprivlist
FROM 
      --join to each grouped view by role, owner, table
      (
      SELECT A.ROLE AS arole, A.owner AS aowner, A.table_name AS atable,
                  --one field for all privileges concatenated with | separator
                  listagg(a.privilege, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a.privilege) AS aprivlist
      FROM role_tab_privs a
      GROUP BY A.ROLE, A.owner, A.table_name
      )
JOIN 
      (
      SELECT b.ROLE as brole, b.owner as bowner, b.table_name as btable,
                  listagg(b.privilege, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY b.privilege) AS bprivlist
      FROM role_tab_privs b
      GROUP BY b.ROLE, b.owner, b.table_name
      )
  -- the roles cannot be equal but the owner, table, and privileges must be
  ON AROLE != bROLE
 AND aowner = bowner
 AND atable = btable
 AND aprivlist = bprivlist
ORDER BY aowner, atable, arole 
;
```

Note that the `LISTAGG` is used only on the privileges within a role, owner, table group. The result of a `LISTAGG' function must fit within the max varchar(4000) or the error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

This query gives a good view of how the table privileges relate.

Comment: That's a really nice approach for my problem. I changed `role_tab_privs` to `dba_tab_privs` and used a `WHERE clause` to only display my roles and not the users. The idea is pretty cool, but the output is kinda messy and "unorganised". I would like to see what they have in common and in what they differentiate from each other. Like in my MWE. I could see at the first glance how the correlate and make a rough estimate of how much % they overlap.

Comment: One thing that might help to organize it the way you want is to `ORDER BY arole, brole, aowner, atable`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using shell scripts.

The code below is not tested, there could be problems with IFS and spaces in file names and maybe a couple of typos.
It also lacks optimization, it loops over all the roles again and again. It should especially be a problem with the "extraction" part, as it makes a new connection to the database for each role.

But still, if it's a one shot thing, I wouldn't mind too much.

You'll need :

a sql file to extract privileges for a role (your request, I added the order by clause because we will diff them later)

```
--extract_privileges.sql
SELECT
  PRIVILEGE,
  TABLE_NAME,
  GRANTABLE
FROM
  SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE
  GRANTEE IN ( '&1' )
ORDER BY
  PRIVILEGE,
  TABLE_NAME,
  GRANTABLE;
```

a configuration file with the roles you want to test :

```
ROLE_1
ROLE_2
...
```

and a shell script :

```
ROLE_FILE='/path/to/the/configuration/file'
EXTRACT_PRIVILEGES_FILE='/path/to/the/sql/script'
TEMP_DIR='/path/to/temp/dir/'
CONNECTION_STRING='user/pass@instance'

IFS='
'

# Make sure we have temp dirs
EXTRACT_DIR='${TEMP_DIR}/extract/'
COMPARE_DIR='${TEMP_DIR}/compare/'

mkdir -p ${EXTRACT_DIR}
mkdir -p ${COMPARE_DIR}

# Extract all privileges
for role in `cat ${ROLE_FILE}`
do
  ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus ${CONNECTION_STRING} @${EXTRACT_PRIVILEGES_FILE} ${role} > ${EXTRACT_DIR}/${role}
done

# Compare privileges
for role1 in `cat ${ROLE_FILE}`
do
  for role2 in `cat ${ROLE_FILE}`
  do
    diff ${EXTRACT_DIR}/${role1} ${EXTRACT_DIR}/${role2} > ${COMPARE_DIR}/${role1}_${role2}
  done
done

# Now you have all the diffs, you can look for those with nothing in it (privileges are the same)
for file in `ls ${COMPARE_DIR}`
do
  #There is certainly a more elegant way to do this.
  if [[`wc -l ${file}` -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo '${file} is empty'
  fi
done
```